# Query for all tasks in specific workspace that are not completed

Tags: asana

I have the following `cURL cmd` running which returns all tasks for a specific `userID` within a specific `workspaceID`, but the "completed=false" part of the `cmd` doesn't influence the data returned. I am trying to exclude all "completed" tasks. Everything else is working as I expected.  Below is the current `cmd` string and a snippet of the data returned back. As you can see one of the returned tasks indicates "completed" is true while the other indicates false.

Anyone see what I may be missing? Thanks in advance for your help.

```
cURL cmd:
curl -u <api-key>: "https://app.asana.com/api/1.0/tasks?workspace=<workspace>&assignee=<teamMemberId>&completed=false&opt_fields=name,assignee,assignee_status,notes,created_at,modified_at,completed_at,due_on,completed&opt_pretty"

output (partial)
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": <ID>,
      "created_at": "2014-03-11T03:34:52.002Z",
      "modified_at": "2014-03-11T23:33:07.544Z",
      "name": "<nameoftask>",
      "notes": "",
      "assignee": {
        "id": <ID>
      },
      "completed": true,
      "assignee_status": "upcoming",
      "completed_at": "2014-03-11T23:33:06.729Z",
      "due_on": "2014-03-11"
    },
    {
      "id": <ID>,
      "created_at": "2014-03-11T23:33:07.196Z",
      "modified_at": "2014-03-11T23:33:07.196Z",
      "name": "<nameoftask>",
      "notes": "",
      "assignee": {
        "id": ID>
      },
      "completed": false,
      "assignee_status": "upcoming",
      "completed_at": null,
      "due_on": "2014-03-14"
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:** You want `completed_since=now`, not `completed=false`.

The `GET /tasks` endpoint doesn't take a parameter `completed` - it does however take `completed_since`, which can take a timestamp (as provided by JS's `.toISOString()`) or the string `"now"`. It always includes incomplete tasks. This is documented in the [API Docs on Tasks](http://developer.asana.com/documentation/#tasks) (specifically the section on "Querying for tasks").

We're looking to improve the way you can filter tasks, but for right now what's documented there is all there is.

Comment: completed_since=now worked perfectly. I really appreciate the feedback.  I poured over the docs before posting, and checked again now, but still don't see anything about completed_since=now.  Would never have gotten there w/o your help.  Thank you again.

Comment: From the docs:

`completed_since`
Only return tasks that are either incomplete, or completed since the given time. 
**Note:** You can also specify now to represent the current time.

Comment: However, I agree the docs aren't as clear as they could be. We'd like to do a complete overhaul (they've just sort of grown organically, but clearly are past the limit of what should be on a single page).

Comment: my bad - I see the detail in the docs now -- i was looking at the top of the Tasks section where it lists the accessible fields and thought that was the limit...I should have kept reading.  Thanks again.